# How to get most frequent categorical value row wise from specific columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data like time and date columns with respect to visit types.

```
Below is the sample data[1]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfnQb.png
```

From the above data I have to get maximum repeated value row wise.

```
I tried like below
out1$MAX1 <- do.call('pmax',c(out1[,2:5],list(na.rm=TRUE)))
```

```
Output of above code[2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CitAa.png
```

It is giving wrong values for some of the rows.For example in the above output for 3rd row we have "SFU","SFU","SFU","SFU,GFU".By using above maximum code getting maximum value as "SFU,GFU".But it has to get "SFU".And I have to add new column that howmany times that visit type is repeated(i.e, for the same 3rd row "SFU" is the maximum value and it is repeated 4 times).
How to achieve that?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not images. Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your original question, you can get the most frequent categorical value row-wise by (1) creating a function that tables a vector and returns the most frequent; and (2) loop through your data frame, unlisting each row and calling your function:

```
# Create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  v1 = sample(c("SFU", "GFU"), replace = TRUE, 5),
  v2 = sample(c("SFU", "GFU"), replace = TRUE, 5),
  v3 = sample(c("SFU", "GFU"), replace = TRUE, 5),
  v4 = sample(c("SFU", "GFU"), replace = TRUE, 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Create function
get_most_frequent <- function(x) {
  tab <- sort(table(x))
  out <-  names(tail(tab, 1))
  out
}

# Loop through data frame
df$most_frequent <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  r <- unlist(df[i,2:5])
  df$most_frequent[i] <- get_most_frequent(r)
}
```

If you need to split up an instance like "SFU, GFU", you can adjust your function accordingly to split the strings by comma.